# Calculating cumulative and bayesian probability

Tags: probability, bayesian, conditional-probability

I have a histogram/count plots of average time a property is in the market. Given this distribution, I'd like to calculate the probability that a similar property will be leased within `'x # of weeks' or less`.

[image]

Would a cumulative probability distribution make sense, in this case or there are other ways of calculating?

i.e `P(X <= x)`, where `X is a similar property` and `x = # of weeks`).

Say, I want to calculate the `P(X <= 4)`, i.e probability that the property is on the market for less than `4 weeks`.

Additionally, I'd also like to calculate conditional / bayesian prb. i.e given a set of property features, calculate the `P(X <= 4)` based on prior distribution. How would we formulate this as a conditional probability distribution problem?

Comment: You can do all of that with a Bayesian model. For example, find a parametric distribution that describes you weeks well and look at different kinds of Bayesian regression / Gaussian processes. Once you got a predicted parameter set for the posterior over the weeks, you can plug them into the CMF and calculate the probability of x < 4

Comment: @CarolEisen  Thanks for the reply. Yes, I have the prior distribution of # of weeks it takes for a property to be leased. I am not sure if I completely understand the latter part of your comment. Is there a link or an worked out example you can share.